# Creating radio button through abcpdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, radio-button, abcpdf

I'm trying to add a radio button to a pdf page I'm rendering through abcpdf. I'm looking at the documentation for abcpdf and it specifies that I use the following code

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
InteractiveForm form = new InteractiveForm (theDoc);
form.AddRadioButtonGroup(new string[2]{"40 610 80 650", "40 660 80 700"}, "RadioGroupField", 0);
```

The problem is that I don't know what assembly InteractiveForm is referencing so the compiler will error on that line. If I simply add a radiobutton to the html page I'm rendering, it will appear in the pdf but will not be able to be interacted with. Does anyone know what I can use to get InteractiveForm to work, or some other workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation I'm referencing can be found at http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/4-examples/18-annotations.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you download and install the full .Net package one of the example projects is called `Annotations`. Within this project is a file called `Annotations.cs` that has the classes that you're looking for.