# C# Annotation types in abcpdf

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, abcpdf

I'm stucked in a lack of documentation related to the link above.

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/18-annotations.htm

My goal is to attach a movie in a pdf document and let a common pdf reader like Acrobat Reader to play it from the pdf itself.

I just can't find the MovieAnnotation class or any of other annotation types, so i think i'm missing something relevant.

Comment: Did you not scroll down the page to the "Movies" section, or just search for "MovieAnnotation"?  _"You may wish to generate a PDF document with movies inserted dynamically at run-time. The code below inserts a Flash movie and a WMV movie …"_

Comment: Yes i did. My point is I can't find the class in VS.

Comment: Ah well you didn't mention that! It's always good to say in your question what you have already done, to save everyone's time. In this case, it looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218940/43846) is what you're after.

Comment: My bad. My lack in english is huge.
Ok, i've found the class in the example projects folder. Am i allowed to feel silly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating radio button through abcpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216198/creating-radio-button-through-abcpdf)